# Why is my jquery function call not working?

Tags: jquery

Here is part of my html code.
My aim is to change the color of the plus button if it has reached the max items (disable) and also the minus button if there are no item to subtract.

```
<div id="plus__button"> <p>Plus</p> </div>
<div id="minus__button"> <p>Minus</p> </div>
```

my css

```
.disable {background-color: #E3E3E3;}


 #plus__button {
    background-color: #FFA600;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 4px;
  }
  
  #minus__button {
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFA600;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 25%;
  }
```

my problem is here the click function works but the minus() and plus() function calls doesn't seem to be working. What am i doing wrong?

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
    var max = document.getElementById('max');
    var counter = document.getElementById("count");


    var counts = 0;
    var maxCount = 20;

    max.innerHTML = maxCount;
    counter.innerHTML = counts;

    //change button color 
    var minus = function (){
        if (counts <= 0){
            $('#minus__button').addClass('disable');
        }else{
            $('#minus__button').removeClass('disable');
        }
    };


    var plus = function () {
        if(counts >= maxCount){
            $('#plus__button').addClass('disable');
        }else{
            $('#plus__button').removeClass('disable');
        }
    };


    //change counter
    $("#plus__button").click(function (){
        if(counts <  maxCount){
            counts++;
            counter.innerHTML = counts;
            plus();
            minus();
        }
    });

    $("#minus__button").click(function(){
        if (counts>0){
            counts --;
            counter.innerHTML = counts;
            plus();
            minus();

         }
    });

    

});
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to CSS?

Comment: Where is `counts` defined?

Comment: where is `maxCount` defined?

Comment: they are both defined variables in the .js file i didn't know i should have put it in when i was asking the question

Comment: You need to remove the disabled in the opposite button click...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just make it as normal function and call it, and btw i prefer using jquery css to set background color instead of adding a class, try the snippet i wish it can help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counts = 0;
  var maxCount = 10;
        $("#result").text(counts);

  //change button color 
  function minus() {
    if (counts <= 0) {
      $('#minus__button').css("background-color", "#E3E3E3");
    } else {
            $('#minus__button').css("background-color", "#FFA600");
    }
  };

minus();
  function plus() {
    if (counts >= maxCount) {
      $('#plus__button').css("background-color", "#E3E3E3");
    } else {
      $('#plus__button').css("background-color", "#FFA600");
    }
  };


  //change counter
  $("#plus__button").click(function() {
    if (counts < maxCount) {
      counts++;
      $("#result").text(counts);
    plus();
    minus();
    }
    });
   $("#minus__button").click(function() {
    if (counts > 0) {
      counts--;
      $("#result").text(counts);
    plus();
    minus();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#counter {
 display:flex;
 position:absolute;
  width:20rem;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#result {
display:inline-flex;
position:relative;
width:50%;
height:15vh;
background:lightblue;
border-radius: 5%;
border: 2px solid gray;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
font-size:5vh;
color:red;
}
#plus__button {
  position:relative;
  background-color: #FFA600;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 4px;
}

#minus__button {
position:relative;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFA600;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
<div class="plusen" id="plus__button">
  <p>+</p>
</div>
<div id="minus__button">
  <p>-</p>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you soo much

Comment: just dun forget to mark the answer as correct to let people know that u got a right answer, regards

Comment: Oh i didn't know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plus and minus functions are variable functions, which can't be called like a normal function.

This article goes in-depth about this: https://dev.to/aaron_powell/named-function-vs-variable-function-11m0

BUT, you can still use these functions.

For example, the MDN article about these different styles of functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions show this

```
var square = function(number) { return number * number }
var x = square(4) // x gets the value 16
```

Thus, for your code to work, it would need to look something like this:

```
<!--add this to your HTML-->
<div id="counter"> <p>Minus</p> </div>

$(document).ready(function (){

    var counts = 4; // specify this
    var maxCount = 12; // specify this
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter'); // get the element where you want the current count to be displayed

    //change button color 
    var minus = function (counts, maxCount){
        if (counts <= 0){
            $('#minus__button').addClass('disable');
        }else{
            $('#minus__button').removeClass('disable');
        }
    };


    var plus = function (counts, maxCount) {
        if(counts >= maxCount){
            $('#plus__button').addClass('disable');
        }else{
            $('#plus__button').removeClass('disable');
        }
    };


    //change counter
    $("#plus__button").click(function (){
        if(counts <  maxCount){
            counts++;
            counter.innerHTML = counts;
            var callPlus = plus(counts, maxCount);
            var callMinus = minus(counts, maxCount);
        }
    });

    

});
```